# Where can I find the "default numeric numpad keys" option in 14.04?

Tags: keyboard, 14.04, menu, system-settings, numlock

[This community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock) explains how to make Ubuntu enable numlock upon login:

> System Settings > Keyboard Layout > Options > Miscellaneous compatibility options
>
> Check "Default numeric keypad keys"

That worked for me in 12.04 but no longer works in 14.04 because the menu structure has changed. How can I access that setting in 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

The same wiki page you linked to says:

"""
Enabling NumLock from lightdm configuration

In Ubuntu 14.04 the above methods of running numlockx don't work. It can be run by changing configuration of LightDM display manager. Edit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf file and add the following line at the end:

greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on

This defines running numlockx command when starting the Unity Greeter. (See more info in /usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz). 
"""

Comment: The first solution on that page, titled "Enable Numlock on Login", which I referred to in my question, has nothing to do with numlockx.